# EhCache 3.x: for a certain entity class, limit quantity of cached instances, possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

How can I configure EhCache 3.5 (xml-config, ehcache.xml) to allow only 100 cached instances for:
*org.company.Foo*? Basically, I have a dozen of entities with separate caching limits wanted.

I've read some sources where they state this is possible, like this one [source](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache) 
This syntax doesn't work for versions 3.x (and I doubt it is the correct config for 2.x too)

```
<ehcache>
    <cache name="org.company.Foo" maxElementsInMemory="100" />
</ehcache>
```

The official documentation is silent (or I missed it somehow, but scrutinized pretty thoroughly) on this topic for versions 2.x as well as for versions 3.x

If not possible, what is the preferred idiom for configuring EhCache?

Thank you.

**P.S.** I am using EhCache 3.5 with Hibernate 5.3 and able to monitor the cache state via VisualVM console through MBeans plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct config would be like this:

```
    <config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core.xsd">

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/>
  </service>

  <cache alias="org.company.Foo">
    <heap>1000</heap>
  </cache>
```